# Updating Primefaces from 3.2 to 3.4 throws java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SKIP_ITERATION

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

I have replaced primefaces-3.2 with primefaces-3.4 RC1. After that, if I open any page, `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SKIP_ITERATION` exception is thrown. What could be the possible problem?

Comment: i think its a compatibility issue. issue has been created here http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4536

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a  compatibility issue with myfaces and some versions of mojarra too

I've reported it on primefaces forum two weeks ago [Failed attempt to replace 3.2 with 3.4.RC1](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=24145)

And it was fixed already,  so you can grab the latest snapshot version of 3.4 from the repository [3.4-SNAPSHOT](http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/primefaces/3.4-SNAPSHOT/)

Comment: Could you please also help with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175047/primefaces-inplace-issue-with-non-ajax-request

Answer (score 3):

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SKIP_ITERATION

So, there's no such field in your JSF runtime environment. The [`VisitHint#SKIP_ITERATION`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/visit/VisitHint.html#SKIP_ITERATION) has been introduced in JSF 2.1. See also the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/visit/VisitHint.html#SKIP_ITERATION):

> ### `SKIP_ITERATION`
>
> `public static final` [`VisitHint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/visit/VisitHint.html) `SKIP_ITERATION`
>
> Hint that indicates that components that normally visit children multiple times (eg. `UIData`) in an iterative fashion should instead visit each child only one time.
>
> **Since**:
>
> 2.1

This `NoSuchFieldError` suggests that you're actually using JSF 2.0 instead of JSF 2.1. Whilst it is indeed PrimeFaces' own fault to depend on a JSF 2.1 specific enhancement while they specify themselves as JSF 2.0 compatible (and thus report it as a bug to them; which is apparently already done by Daniel), you could theoretically also just solve it by upgrading JSF 2.0 to JSF 2.1. Mojarra and MyFaces 2.1.x versions are JSF 2.1 implementations.