# Primefaces inplace issue with non-ajax request

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces inplace editor. (tried primefaces 3.2, 3.3, 3.4RC1, and 3.4 snapshot)

When form is submitted through non-ajax request, and some other required field in the form was not filled, then the page should reload and show the required message. But what actually happens is: Along with page-reload and requiredMessage, the inplace editor is already being shown. How to solve this problem?

**Sample Code to reproduce the problem**

```
<h:form prependId="false">
    <p:inplace editor="true" widgetVar="X">
        <p:inputTextarea value="#{smsAlertBean.alertText}" />
    </p:inplace>
</h:form>
<h:form prependId="false">
    <p:selectOneMenu required="true" requiredMessage="Please select">
                <!-- your values -->
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    <p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{smsAlertBean.dummyAction}" ajax="false" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: I guess you can't place them all in one form ?

Comment: No I can't place them in one form. But placing them in one form still does not help.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand "already being shown". What exactly do you mean with "already" here? Was it already shown before you submit the form?

Comment: I mean : 1 form and instead of `ajax="false"` do `process="@form" update="@form"`

Comment: Oh, it shows without user interaction when you submit the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd bet that this is a bug in `<p:inplace>`. From `InplaceRenderer#encodeMarkup()` method:

```
boolean validationFailed = context.isValidationFailed();
String displayStyle = validationFailed ? "none" : "inline";
String contentStyle = validationFailed ? "inline" : "none";
```

It doesn't check if the validation failure concerns "own" form and would thus always display on a validation failure, regardless of the submitted form. There's not really much you can do against this other than editing the PrimeFaces source code, creatnig a custom renderer and/or posting a bug report.

You could workaround this by manually closing the inplace editor with help of JavaScript on the `widgetVar`. It has a `cancel()` function which closes the editor.

```
<p:commandButton binding="#{foo}" value="Submit" action="#{smsAlertBean.dummyAction}" ajax="false" />
<h:outputScript rendered="#{param.containsKey(foo.clientId)}">X.cancel();</h:outputScript>
```

*(this script thus get rendered when the command button is actually pressed)*

This has however only an ugly effect on slow machines/browsers. The inplace editor flashes. Consider [reporting it as a bug](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/list) to the PrimeFaces guys, that the `InplaceRenderer` should first check if the validation failure concerns own form or not.

Comment: Already reported as bug(Please vote):
http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4473&can=8&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20TargetVersion%20Reporter%20Owner%20Summary

Comment: Instead of using the `cancel()` function (which causes an ajax update) you can call `hide()`.

Comment: @siebz0r: Hmm, I haven't noticed the ajax request in first place, but I observed that `cancel()` immediately hides, while `hide()` fades out very visibly. This can perhaps be tuned by providing a different and better `effect` and `effectSpeed` attribute.

Comment: `cancel()` calls an update to be sure to reset any input element. `hide()` however 'just hides'.